How to use Clerk with Remix for localization?
Use Clerk in a Remix application's root.tsx file:
import { ClerkApp } from "@clerk/remix";
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { enUS, jaJP } from "@clerk/localizations";

interface LoaderData {
  locale: string;
}

function App() {
  const { locale } = useLoaderData<LoaderData>(); // It can be changed by client value

  return (
    <html lang={locale}>
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Outlet />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

const enLocalization = {
  ...enUS,
  ...{
    signUp: { start: { subtitle: "{{applicationName}}" } },
  },
};

const jaLocalization = {
  ...jaJP,
  ...{
    signUp: { start: { subtitle: "{{applicationName}}" } },
  },
};

// How to set localization based on user locale browser language?

export default ClerkApp(App, { localization: enLocalization });

In the document, it provide ClerkApp outside the App function:
https://clerk.com/docs/references/remix/clerk-app
But if the locale check is inside the App function, how to set localization to ClerkApp?

Did you manage to figure this out?

Faced the same problem today and as ClerkApp returns a JSX.Element you can achieve this by wrapping your App with Clerk and returning the ClerkApp function result as an element.
UPDATE: Change return <AppWithClerk /> to return AppWithClerk();
Example:
function App() {
  return <Outlet />;
}

export default function ClerkWrapper() {
  const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  const AppWithClerk = ClerkApp(App, {
    localization: data.locale === "pt" ? ptBR : enUS,
    appearance: {
      ...(data.theme === "dark" ? { baseTheme: dark } : {}),
    },
  });

  return AppWithClerk();
}

